# Compare two lists of numbers, need to check the range of value in A filel with first 2 columns of B file

Tags: awk

Input files:

`A.txt` contains:

```
111
222
223
344
100002
99991
```

`B.txt` contains:

```
100 199 A
200 299 B
300 399 C
400 499 D
```

I want the output like this

```
111 A
222 B
223 B
344 C
```

Comment: It's completely unclear what the pattern here is

Comment: How is this a comparison? What is the like between the input and output? (edit question)

Comment: 111 falls between the range of 100 to 199 so it's mapped with 3rd column value A

Comment: Ranges perhaps? But yes, please be explicit; edit your question.

Comment: I would like to get the mapping of number from a.txt in b.txt and get the output as specified.

Comment: Comparison is based on 1st column in a.txt which falls in 1st and 2nd column in b.txt and give 3 re column output ..

Comment: So is anything wrong with the two answers given? You might comment on them or accept if it works fine for you...

Answer (score 2):

You want to output the values for `B.txt` that fall within a range defined by `A.txt`, together with the label for that range.

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR { rs[$3] = $1; re[$3] = $2; next } { for (s in rs) if ($1 >= rs[s] && $1 <= re[s]) { print $1, s; next } }' A.txt B.txt
111 A
222 B
223 B
344 C
```

The first block would parse the ranges in `A.txt` and save the start and end for each range in the two arrays `rs` (for start) and `re` (for end).  These arrays are indexed by the label assigned to the range in the file.

When parsing the second file (which will be done in the second block of the code), we loop through each range in these variables and test wether the number falls within one of them.  If it does, the number is outputted together with the label of the range (in the code, the label is extracted into `s` for "string").

---

The main difference between the above code and [the code presented by pLumo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/531638/116858) is that my code would iterate through the ranges for each given input number to find the range that contains the number, while their code stores each integer of each range for faster lookup.  Their code would be fast to use on a large number of lookups in small ranges, while my code is trades speed for memory efficiency and would be preferable if your ranges are large or you have just a few lookups to make.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `awk`:

```
awk '
    FNR==NR{for(n=$1;n<=$2;n++)v[n]=$3}
    FNR!=NR{if(v[$1])print $1,v[$1]}
' B.txt A.txt
```

First row creates an array `v` with value being `$3` for all numbers between `$1` and `$2` from file `B.txt`.

Second row reads the value from that array with the number given in `A.txt`.

Output:

```
111 A
222 B
223 B
344 C
```

Answer (score -2):

```
awk -v test="$(awk '{print $1+0}' A.txt)" '{ if ($1 > test && $2 < test) {print test,$3} }'  B.txt
```

Comment: Did you actually test this?